Slack's conversation.history method doesn't return messages from DMs
I am using slack conversations.history API to fetch messages from DM's. Slack calls this im i believe. I get an empty list of messages. I do have the relevant scopes and permissions and some messages in my DMs.
For public channels it lists down the messages just fine but not for DMs. Has anyone encountered this issue before?
There are no authorization and authentication issues as i can list messages from public channels and also when requesting DMS at the start it was asking for the right scopes when provided it returns empty messages.

Based on my understanding of the Slack Documentation I, believe you need to provide more parameters in the conversation.history request you are making to  fetch direct messages. you will also need to add iam:history scope in bot and user token as well to your application.
References:-
https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history#retrieving-message-history-from-a-direct-message
https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history
https://api.slack.com/scopes/im:history
Hope, you find these above references useful. Good luck :)

hey man thanks for the help. As for the issue I do have Im:history scope added to the bot scopes and i am using the bot token and this is how i am calling the API to get DMS.
https://slack.com/api/conversations.history?channel= starts with "D".

i do get the response but there are no messages in it surprisingly.

@JunaidSoomro Have you tried adding im:history scope to user token as well? if not do give it a try. also, try giving all the scopes mentioned in the API request if above case does not work for you.

yes im:history is there and now i tried to add all those scopes to the user token just to check if it will work but sadly it shows empty messages. btw i am using a trial account for slack i don't think that should be a problem.

In Slack API the direct messages also have a channel id which needs to be passed to the conversations_history method.
Let's get the dm history step by step:

get the user id of the users you want to get the history
for each user get the open conversations

conversation = client.conversations_open(users=user_id)


get the conversation history based on the conversation channel id of the dm conversation

history = client.conversations_history(channel=conversation["channel"]["id])

reference: Slack API
